# SonarQube Plugin create new rules after server start

Tags: plugins, import, sonarqube, rules

I want to create a SonarQube plugin which provides the functionality of rule creation. The rules are ought to be provided by an importer which parses a however-looking (custom) definition file and creates (custom) rules from that definition file. This importer is started by user action.

I did not found a possibility to create new rules after server start. Do you know a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is through [rule templates](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Rules#Rules-RuleTemplatesandCustomRules). Otherwise, all rules must be registered at server startup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is exactly what I'm looking for. I have a rule template and want to make a certain rule instance from it. How can it be achieved in a ProfileImporter?